# Where in the stack to implement a rate limiter

Tags: python, networking, server, rate-limiting

I plan to develop a rate limiter (based on IP address counts), preferably in python.
It needs to be able to see the source IP of a request (then do some stuff) and drop or forward the request.

The question I have is, *where* exactly should I implement this system?

I had the following thoughts:

- since most rate limiters are deployed on web servers, this seems the best place to implement mine too. The problem is, that NGINX, etc. don't seem to support python scripting and I don't want to use the existing rate limiting tool of these servers
- I could also write my own web server but I don't want to reinvent the wheel here
- what should work is to implement it as Django/Flask middleware, however, this would not perform as well as directly on the server

So ideally, the closer "down the stack", the better it performs.

I'd appreciate any advice or suggestions!

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.